# Is it possible to erase an array of structs with the brace initializer?

Tags: c++11

I was wondering: I have an array of structs with some data. If I want to erase all the data and leave all the values into the array of structs as default, is it possible to use the C++11 bracket initializer?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
 int i;
 char a;
}mystruct;

int main()
{
    mystruct structure[2];
    structure{};
    structure[0].i = 69;
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; // Should print 69
    structure{};
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; //Should print 0

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Currently my compiler says expected ; before {, so it seems it does not recognise the brace initializer.

Comment: Try to compile and run?

Comment: I am not able to compile it right now. That is why I am asking

Comment: `structure[0].int`???

Comment: I meant structure[0].i

Comment: there's no "reinitialization" (which looks like what you're trying to do). with the advent of uniform initialization you can have assigment using `= {...}` syntax for construction of temporary for the argument of the assignment operator. arrays can't be assigned to, `std::array`s can, since they have an implicit assignment operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive arrays are not copyable in C++ - [use `std::array` instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/172b4cbb9bcae450):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct mystruct {
  int i;
  char a;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<mystruct, 2> structure = {};
    structure[0].i = 69;
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; // Should print 69
    structure = {};
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; //Should print 0
}
```

[If your compiler whines about missing initializers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7514771ccc6626e4), [simply double them up to `{{}}`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c04c53c852419f2).

Answer (score 1):

Lines `structure{};` are invalid. If you want to erase all structures in your array I do not see how to do it with single assignment. But you can use such assignment on individual array elements, e.g.

```
structure[0] = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a default constructor for your struct in order to have defined values for its fields.

For example:

```
struct mystruct {
    int a  = 1;
    char c = 'a';
};

mystruct s1;
assert(s1.a == 1);
```

Then you can "erase" by assigning a default constructed value:

```
s1.a = 2;
s1 = mystruct();
assert(s1.a == 1);
```

Doing this for an array is IMHO impossible.

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned that when equal-assigning a non-static member, the struct will no longer be an aggregate. That is, aggregate-initialization is no longer possible:

```
mystruct x{1,2};  // fails to compile
```

while this calls the implicit default-ctor:

```
mystruct x{};
```

Answer (score 0):

A probable solution (if you can include `algorithm`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef struct{
 int i;
 char a;
 void erase(){i=0; a=0;}
}mystruct;

int main()
{
    mystruct structure[2];
    //structure{};
    structure[0].i = 69;
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; // Should print 69
    //structure{};
    std::for_each(structure,  structure+2, [&](mystruct& s){s.erase();} );
    cout << structure[0].i << endl; //Should print 0

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I tried to keep the code clean with your original data structure (ie, avoid `std::vector`). About curly braces, I don´t think C++11 standard will let you to overload it (if someone is sure about it, please comment!).